# Draw a rectangle randomly on an image

Tags: image, swing, netbeans-7, jlabel

I have tried the code below for generating a rectangle randomly on an image, but it's not working. Please help solve this.

```
Rectangle e;
public mypanel() 
{
    initComponents();
     v();
}

protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g)
  {
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)jLabel2.getGraphics();
    g2.drawRect(n,n1,40,40);
}

public void v()
{
   e=jLabel2.getBounds();
    e4=e.getX();
   k=jLabel2.getWidth();
   o=jLabel2.getHeight();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ok2'"+e4+"'");
   System.out.print(k+" "+o);
   for(int i=f.x;i<k*o;k++)
   {
       e1= rand.nextInt(k);
       e2=rand.nextInt(o);
       repaint(e1,e2,40,40);
       break;
   }
}
```

I'm always getting java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Where are you getting `NullPointerException`. Please mention stack trace.

Comment: Why are your Graphics objects final?

Comment: There's your problem: `jLabel2.getGraphics();`. Don't call `getGraphics` on a component. You should read about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/. In this case, the solution might (partially) consist of using `g.drawRect(n,n1,40,40);` (and not `g2`).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  But definitely go through the link provided by @Marco13, that will solve the core of the problem.

Comment: @Braj:  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javaapplication5.mypanel.mm(mypanel.java:76)
 at javaapplication5.mypanel.v(mypanel.java:62)
 at javaapplication5.mypanel.<init>(mypanel.java:44)
 at javaapplication5.rect.<init>(rect.java:22)
 at javaapplication5.rect$2.run(rect.java:115)

Comment: @Marco:Sir if i use 'g' instead of 'g2' the rectangle will be drawn outside the image(jlabel).g2 is working properly.Here my problem is draw the rectangle randomley on the image(at a time one) when the program runs.That time the errors occurs.I read the above tutorial.I have already drawn the rect.So I cant find the solution from that

Comment: The exception does not seem to be caused by the code that you posted. If you post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , we will be able to help you very quickly. (Preferably, post an example where you do NOT use method names like `v()`. Seriously, what is `v` supposed to mean?)